python notify thread exit with multiple loops
I have code with two loops in thread, I wish to exit the thread after done in main thread.
Currently I use a global variable to notify it but it looks not good since multiple thread access the same variable. And code looks ugly to break in multiple loops.
What's graceful way to exit thread in this case?
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import threading

bexit = False
def threadLoop(idx):
    global bexit
    while bexit == False:
        #do something here
        while True:
            #do something here
            if bexit == True:
                break
        if bexit == True:
            break
    bexit = False
    return

def main():
    global bexit
    thread = threading.Thread(target=threadLoop, args=(0, ))
    thread.start()
    #do something here
    bexit = True
    thread.join()        
    return

main(


There is nothing fundamentally wrong with what your doing, but it could certainly be more Pythonic:

Tests like while bexit == False: are more clearly expressed as while not bexit:
You have unnecessary return statements at the end of a function.

Also, when you break out of the inner loop you have a test if bexit == True: break. This is unnecessary since you will immediately be testing bexit in the while bexit == False: that will immediately be executed when you break out of the inner loop.
See the comments in the code below:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#import subprocess  #Unused
import threading
import time

bexit = False

def threadLoop(idx):
    #global bexit  # Not required
    while not bexit:  # More Pythonic
        time.sleep(.1)  #do something here
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)  #do something here
            if bexit:  # More Pythonic
                break  # or just return since no code follows the outer loop
    # Unnecessary (but not wrong):
    #return
    

def main():
    global bexit

    thread = threading.Thread(target=threadLoop, args=(0, ))
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)  #do something here
    bexit = True
    thread.join()
    # Unnecessary:
    #return

main()

Or without all the comments:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import threading
import time

bexit = False

def threadLoop(idx):
    while not bexit:
        time.sleep(.1)  #do something here
        while True:
            time.sleep(.1)  #do something here
            if bexit:
                break


def main():
    global bexit

    thread = threading.Thread(target=threadLoop, args=(0, ))
    thread.start()
    time.sleep(1)  #do something here
    bexit = True
    thread.join()

main()

